# Laravel eloquent ,has many in multi table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3, relation, multi-table

i have three tables inventory,products,product_category

in table:**inventory**

```
id  product_name  quantity
1      2             24
2      2             54653
3      1             34
```

here product_name is foreign key..this table has many relation with **product** table

in table:**products**

```
id  name        type_fk_id
1    pc             1
2   laptop          2
3  servo_oil        2
```

here type_fk_id is foreign key..this table has many relation with **product_category** table

in table:**product_category**

```
id  type_name       
1    PC            
2    oil         
3   servo_oil
```

there is no foreign key in product_category table

in my controller

```
$data=Inventory::all();
return view('inv_view',compact('data'));
```

in inv_view view

```
@foreach($data as $inv)
{{$inv->id}}
{{$inv->qty}}

@endforeach
```

i want to show in the view part also product name and category thats mean

```
id  quantity   product_name  category
1    34           pc           pc
2    436         servo_oil     oil
```

i don't know how to access or get this data in view using laravel eloquent relation
i know how to use **hasmanyThrough** in model to access `product_category->product->inventory`...how can i use **inverse of hasmanythrough** thats mean `inventory->product->product_category`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$data=Inventory::with('product.product_category')->get();
return view('inv_view',compact('data'));
```

> Inside View

```
@foreach($data as $inv)
  {{ $inv->id }}
  {{ $inv->qty }}
  {{ $inv->product->name }}
  {{ $inv->product->product_category->type_name  }}
@endforeach
```

Define your model relation like below:

> App\Inventory

```
public function product() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Product', 'product_name'); 
}
```

> App\Product

```
public function inventory(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Inventory');
}

public function product_category() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\ProductCategory', 'type_fk_id');   
}
```

> App\ProductCategory

```
public function product() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Product');   
}
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

Comment: getting this error after using ur code ===RelationNotFoundException in RelationNotFoundException.php line 20:
Call to undefined relationship [product] on model [App\Inventory].---------one thing how inventory will know that its foreign key is product_name ?????

Comment: You need to create relation Inside Inventory model?

Comment: can u kindly provide what will be the relation inside inventory??? do u meaning hasmanythrough??

Answer (score 0):

Try to do like this

Join your table with foreign key

```
$products = DB::table('products')
  ->join('inventory', 'products.id', '=', 'inventory.product_id')
  ->join('product_category', 'products.id', '=', 'product_category.product_id')
  ->select('products.*','product_category.category as category_name')
  ->get();
```